# inline script : prettyPhoto setting deeplinking to false not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, prettyphoto

This is suppose to be simple but I can not figure it out. I'm using WordPress prettyPhoto plugin for my project and I'm trying to set deeplinking to false (deeplinking:false). In the Chrome console, I inserted the javascript below to test it out and it works, but when I tried to insert the same code into an inline script in the functions.php, it doesn't work. The console.log() only works.

Note: The prettyphoto library is loaded at the bottom of the footer and the inline script is loaded right after.

```
function inline_script_footer(){ ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {  
        console.log('check');  

        var j = jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto'], a[rel^='lightbox']").prettyPhoto({
            deeplinking: false
        });

        console.log(j);

        if (j) {
            console.log('yes');
        } else {
            console.log('no');
        }

    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'inline_script_footer', 100);
```

If anyone could please assist me, that would be great.

Comment: Sheesh, Dislike prettyphoto but I figured it out. Thanks for viewing.

Comment: If anyone stumbled on this issue, here's what I did:

    `<script type="text/javascript">
 (function($) {
  /** Remove prettyPhoto hashtag URL **/
  $("img").on("click", function() {
   $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    deeplinking : false
   });
  });

 })(jQuery);

    </script>`